# Opening image from github with python PIL image.open()

Tags: python

I am hoping to classify some line drawings with a pretrained resnet model and am loading them from a github page. I think the error is coming from me setting up the location of the file wrong, but any help would be appreciated.

The link for the github is [here](https://github.com/AlexSwiderski/Images/tree/main/pnt)

Here is my code:

```
loc = 'https://github.com/AlexSwiderski/Images/tree/main/pnt'
fname1 = 'ambulance_resized.png'
response = requests.get(loc + fname1)
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)).resize((256, 256))
data = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(image)[:, :, :3]) / 255.
```

My error is as follows:

```
UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-6e447d67525f> in <module>()
      4 fname1 = 'ambulance_resized.png'
      5 response = requests.get(loc + fname1)
----> 6 image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)).resize((256, 256))
      7 data = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(image)[:, :, :3]) / 255.
      8 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2894         warnings.warn(message)
   2895     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
-> 2896         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   2897     )
   2898 

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f61e16decb0>
```

Comment: `https://github.com/AlexSwiderski/Images/blob/main/pnt/ambulance_resized.png` is not an image, it's a webpage. This is really easy to see if you just navigate to that URL in a browser. The actual image itself is at the URL `https://github.com/AlexSwiderski/Images/raw/main/pnt/ambulance_resized.png`.

Comment: I know that, but with the line ```response = requests.get(loc + fname1)``` was intended to use the location and filename

Comment: In that case you're missing a slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add a slash before the string, otherwise the concatenated path would be

"https://github.com/AlexSwiderski/Images/tree/main/pntambulance_resized.png"

Which is invalid.

```
loc = 'https://github.com/AlexSwiderski/Images/tree/main/pnt'
fname1 = '/ambulance_resized.png'
response = requests.get(loc + fname1)
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)).resize((256, 256))
data = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(image)[:, :, :3]) / 255.
```